# Realtime Graph in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, real-time

Trying to implement a real time graph for sensor data in Jetpack Compose, but I am struggling with the correct way to pass the sensor data to the graph.

The app is receiving new sensor data over BLE every 40ms in a Kotlin class, and I would like to pass these to a custom Compose Line Chart. I tried implementing it with a Stateflow, which is then collected in the Composable to fill a list, but this is too slow:

DataReceiver:

```
private val _liveData = MutableStateFlow(0)
// The UI collects from this StateFlow to get its state updates
val liveData: StateFlow<Int> = _liveData

override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
    characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
    value: ByteArray,
) {
    _liveData.value = value[0].toInt()
}
```

This part works fine and the data is set to the liveData value.
But when I try to collect this from the composable e.g.:

```
LaunchedEffect(DataReceiver.liveData) {
    DataReceiver.liveData
        .collect {
            Log.d("BLE", "Value: " + it.value.toString())
        }
}
```

I am missing some values, like this is not fast enough to capture all the data from the flow?

How can I improve this or what is the best way to receive these values from an event and add it to a list in a composable?

Comment: Flow collection in compose is done with `collectAsStateWithLifecycle`, not with a `LaunchedEffect`. Also, your flow only contains an `Int`; for a graph, you would need a list of `Int`s, or even a map with key/value pairs. That should be created before compose collects the flow.

Comment: Yes that was the inital idea, but then how do I get the single in from collectAsState into the list ?  Adding another snapShowFlow to get the state back into a flow inside the compose does not seem correct either

Comment: As I said before, you would collect a flow of `List`s, not a flow of `Int`s. Getting the single values into a list is done before. It could be done by implementating your `onCharacteristicChanged` callback as part of a `callbackFlow`.

Comment: Ah I see, but I do not want to store the data inside the DataReceiver

Comment: To let the `callbackFlow` manage the list seems the most elegant solution, though, you can store the list wherever you want, just make sure your composable only gets a list of ints to collect.

Comment: I never used callbackFlow, but I will look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions by @Leviathan I came up with this solution, in case anyone looks for something similar:

```
override fun dataFlow() = callbackFlow<ByteArray> {
    val characteristicChangedListener = object: ICharacteristicChangedListener {
        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
            deviceAddress: String,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
            value: ByteArray
        ) {
            val uuid = characteristic.uuid.toString().uppercase()
            trySend(it)
        }
    }

    AndroidBLEDeviceHandler.registerCharacteristicChangedListener(characteristicChangedListener);

    awaitClose {
        AndroidBLEDeviceHandler.unregisterCharacteristicChangedListener(characteristicChangedListener);
    }
}
```

Then I created a viewmodel for my graph composable and there I collect the flow and put the data in a list:

```
    dataList = mutableListOf()
    ...
    streamEMGJob = viewModelScope.launch {
        chartDataManager.dataFlow().collect {
            //Process the data
            dataList.add(it)
        }
    }
```

Not sure if this is the best solution but it works fast enough and does not lose any datapoints